# phpMyAdmin error when moving database from one host to another

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, phpmyadmin

I am moving a Drupal mySQL database from one server to another using phpMyAdmin.

The move is from a functioning live site to local mac MAMP server to allow for some development work. I am using the SQL format for the export. I am also selecting 'Add drop table...' under Object creation options for exporting. I am using the default settings for the import into the MAMP database.

All of the tables are created and the site loads on the local host. As far as I can tell, everything is working fine. But I get the following error/report from the MAMP phpMyAdmin.

```
Error
SQL query:





MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

There is no sql query shown, just a bunch of empty lines.

Here are the first few lines of the exported database file I'm trying to import.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: May 05, 2014 at 01:02 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.32-cll
-- PHP Version: 5.3.17

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `userid_databasename`
--
USE 'userid_databasename';

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `actions`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `actions`;
```

Can I ignore this error since everything seems to be working? Or is there something I need to change to avoid this error?

Comment: It looks like the error was not effecting the import. I solved it by deleting a string of special characters in the last line of the sql file.

Answer (score 1):

Tipp:
Just copy / paste one statement after the other in phpadmin and execute it. So you will see where it crashes.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It is a big file with many, many statements. I did not find a problematic statement, but while looking over the file I found that the last line of this 68,000+ file was a string of special characters. Deleting that line made the error go away.